# How to make Web page to not wait for a response after sending a GET request

Tags: html

I am trying to make this web site that resides in Google Drive control a LED(on/off) via esp8266 and arduino. Partially i've succeded in doing what i want  by sending to the IP of the module that communicates with the arduino a GET request witch parses it and acts accordingly. ie GET /?LED1=on HTTP/1.1

Problem is that whenever i press a button in the web site it sends the GET request and then it waits for a response from the other end (arduino),and the browser keeps loading until eather I close the connection from the arduino or I reply something like HTTP/1.1 200 OK and then close the conection.
In the first case browser shows the message that was unable to load the page and in second case it simply shows a blank page.

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>LED Control</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="http://78.87.xxx.xx:333/?LED1=on"><button>LED 1 On</button></a>
</body>
</html>
```

I just want to send that LED1=on string somehow without causing the page attempt to load anything back.

Comment: It tries to load the page the `a` links to? You should probably just basic JavaScript to ping that

Comment: Yeah, with simple javascript you could send an asynchromous query and it won't need an answer

Comment: @HéctorE Don't forget about CORS.

Answer (score 0):

## A reusable solution

Modify your HTML to be something like this:

```
<button class="get" data-url="http://78.87.xxx.xx:333/?LED1=on">LED 1 On</button>
```

Now add this JavaScript:

```
window.onload = function () {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.get'), function(el) {
        el.onclick = function () {
             // Use this trick to perform CORS requests too
             var req = new Image();
             req.src = this.dataset.url;
             // The following 7 lines are completely optional
             req.onload = function () {
                 // Was successful
             };
             req.onerror = function (error) {
                 // Encountered an error
                 alert('An error occurred while performing the request. + ' error);
             };
        };
    });
};
```

---

Now any element with the class "get" when clicked, will send a request to the URL. This won't change the page either. If